# Compact embedding in weighted Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I have a question concerning Sobolev's embedding.

Let (for simplicity) $\Omega=\left(  0,1\right)  $. Then it is well known by
Rellich's theorem that $H^{1}\left(  \Omega\right)  $ is compactly embedded in
$L^{2}\left(  \Omega\right)  $.

The situation becomes unclear to me, if I consider a weighted $H^{1}\left(  \Omega\right)  $ space by introducing
the norm $\left\Vert u\right\Vert _{1,w}:=\left\Vert u\right\Vert
_{L^{2}\left(  \Omega\right)  }+\left\Vert xu^{\prime}\right\Vert
_{L^{2}\left(  \Omega\right)  }$ and letting $H_{w}^{1}\left(  \Omega\right)
$ be the closure of smooth and compactly support functions in $\Omega$.

Question: Is $H_{w}^{1}\left(  \Omega\right)  $ compactly embedded in
$L^{2}\left(  \Omega\right)  $ or is the embedding only continuous?